# Can we access xml elements in another xml?

Tags: xml, lxml

I wanted to know if we can use the value of the xml node in another xml

```
XML 1:

<testnode file = "abc/blah.xml" xpath= "root1/root2">ValuePassed</testnode>

blah.xml:

<root1>
    <root2>
        <sometagval>
    </root2>
</root1>
```

Now in the above example , I would like to access testnode element value in blah.xml.

Can some one give me a suggestion on this

Answer (score 0):

You can use Entities to achieve this. Having a dtd depends on your requirement. Here you are defining all the chapters in their respective XMLs and defining them as ENTITY and using them inside book.xml. Check out the sample usage below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE book SYSTEM "book.dtd" [
<!ENTITY chapter1 SYSTEM "chapter1.xml">
<!ENTITY chapter2 SYSTEM "chapter2.xml">
<!ENTITY chapter3 SYSTEM "chapter3.xml">
]>
<book>
  <title>My Book Title</title>
  &chapter1;
  &chapter2;
  &chapter3;
</book>
```

But the other and better option is to use ***XInclude***. You can also use absolute URLs as appropriate.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<book xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">
  <title>My Book Title</title>
  <xi:include href="chapter1.xml"/>
  <xi:include href="chapter2.xml"/>
  <xi:include href="chapter3.xml"/>
</book>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply , but in the above case.. can you please give me a syntax for the 2 xmls , the XML from which we are using XPATH and passing the value and the XML which is using the value passed

Comment: <book> is the actual XML which is including chapter XMLs. Chapter XML could be as simple as <?xml version="1.0"?><chapter><title>Introduction</title><content>chapter content</content></chapter>. You can have the name space and schema/dtd declarations as needed.

Comment: thanks .. understood, but the problem am facing here is .. from book.xml we are calling chapter1.xml and inside chapter1.xml say it has to click pagenumber that is user driven from book.xml

Comment: Okie ..I need to achieve some thing like this: function(x){print x}    call function(10)... this should be done using XML

Comment: @vineel, if you need to clarify the question, please **update the question**. Don't use comments for that.